# Installing wkhtmltoimage in Debian 6.0 (squeeze)

Tags: debian, installation, debian-squeeze, deb, wkhtmltopdf

How to install wkhtmltoimage in 64 bit amd debian ?

I tried

```
wget http://wkhtmltopdf.googlecode.com/files/wkhtmltopdf-0.9.9-static-amd64.tar.bz2
tar xvjf wkhtmltopdf-0.9.9-static-amd64.tar.bz2
mv wkhtmltopdf-amd64 /usr/bin/wkhtmltopdf
```

This installed only wkhtmltopdf , not wkhtmltoimage.

I tried also to load

http://wkhtmltopdf.googlecode.com/files/wkhtmltoimage-0.9.9-static-amd64.tar.bz2

but this file does not exists.

I looked into downloads page

http://wkhtmltopdf.org/downloads.html

and opened debian deb file. Archiever shows that file contains only single binary:

[image: deb contents]

It looks like wkhtmltoimage is not included.

If windows package from this location is installed it installs both wkhtmltoimage and wkhtmltopdf.

How to install wkhtmltoimage also in Debian x64 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your best bet is to build it from source. You can find the sources here:

http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/wkhtmltopdf/0.12.2.1/wkhtmltox-0.12.2.1.tar.bz2

Instructions on how to build are here:

https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf/blob/0.12.2.1/INSTALL.md#others

If you think that's too difficult, I recommend to upgrade your Squeeze machine to Wheezy, but that may have a lot of impact on the system. There are precompiled packages that contain wkhtmltoimage for wheezy, however. You can find them here:

http://wkhtmltopdf.org/downloads.html

Comment: For wkhtmltopdf I copied statically compiled executable from http://wkhtmltopdf.googlecode.com/files/wkhtmltopdf-0.9.9-static-amd64.tar.bz2  Maybe there is similar file for wkhtmltoimage for Squeeze ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this link for image converter:

> [wkhtmltoimage 0.10.0_rc2 amd64](http://wkhtmltopdf.googlecode.com/files/wkhtmltoimage-0.10.0_rc2-static-amd64.tar.bz2)